# Looking for open source Delphi project with good unit test coverage

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, tdd

For educational reasons I am looking for an open source Delphi project with good unit test coverage. Projects which are under Test Driven Development are preferred. The size of the project doesn't matter.

Subject should be business or game development, but no web projects.

Any hints?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the suggestions, but I prefer projects where the requests come from "normal" users, not from programmers like for a CRM or ERP system. For example, a task planner or jump-and-run game. Has anybody seen something like this?

Comment: Those kinds of projects are rarely open source. Remember, also, that relatively few Delphi projects are open source themselves.

Comment: @David That is the reason why I ask here, I don't find them. :-)

Comment: @David: Really?  From what I've seen there's a pretty strong open-source Delphi community.

Comment: @Mason I'm not saying that. I just think that there is a lot more closed source Delphi code than open source.  And that the proportion of closed/open is more slanted to closed than some other languages.

Comment: If I was doing this for a classroom, I would actually make my own small game, and demonstrate test coverage, UI and model separation, and other things, in exactly the way I wanted it. I doubt I would find something suitable for classroom use out there, for ANY language, unless it was prepared for the classroom in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that "normal" users rarely care about either open source or unit testing. The vast majority of FOSS is designed by programmers for programmers. Interest from "normal" users comes only after the UI, features and stability have matured.

Comment: @Warren Small examples are good for understanding UnitTests but not for motivation because they don't show, that UnitTests works well in large, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We tried to implement test driven development for all root classes of our ORM Framework.

All low-level (numerical or UTF-8 text conversion) and high-level features (RTTI, ORM, JSON, database, client/server) were tested before their implementation.

We even made some basic regression tests about the encryption or pdf generation part.

And the tests were then inserted into the [main documentation](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=16) of some medical project (to follow the [IEC 62304](http://www.google.at/search?q=IEC+62304) requirements). Every release triggered more than 1,000,000 unitary tests. Then manual tests (human-driven on real hardware with working robotic workstations) were performed. Those high-level tests were written using the same documentation tool, which generated a cross-reference matrix to track that all tests passed before any release.

Perhaps not a perfect match, but at least a real use case, in a real world Delphi application, developed for the medical area (and if you know about FDA regulation, you know what I mean). :)

See [this article in our forum](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=72).

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/).  It makes heavy use of generics, and the author has an extensive test suite to make sure that the collections will work properly and not break the compiler.

Comment: A great aspect of having unit tests for a library like this, is that developers can use the unit tests to figure out how to use the functionality.  By examining the tests, you know exactly what to expect, you understand the capabilities, and you know how to use it. +1

Comment: @Chris This is true. One good aspect of the test-driven development is that you will write the specs inside the tests code. And sometimes, code is easier to understand than plain English - even more if you're no native, like me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Delphiwebscript boasts about their coverage: http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/

Answer (score 3):

IIRC [tiopf](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/) has a large testsuite.

Free Pascal maybe even has a larger one, but it depends if that can be regarded Delphi enough for your purposes (**3860** tests that pretty much pinpoint "Delphi, the language"). They have their own unit testing framework "fpcunit"

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/wiki/Introduction).

From its introduction page:

> DeHL is an abbreviation that stands
>   for Delphi Helper Library. DeHL is a
>   library which makes use of the newly
>   introduced features in Delphi 2009;
>   features like Generics and Anonymous
>   Methods. It tries to fill in the gaps
>   in the Delphi RTL by providing what
>   most developers already have in other
>   development platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [JediCodeFormat](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/) & [DelphiCodeToDoc](http://dephicodetodoc.sourceforge.net/).
Both are open source projects with many automated tests build with DUnit framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think [instantobjects](https://instantobjects.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/instantobjects) is good place to study. This is one of the best OPF in delphi.It also contains unit test built with DUnit

Answer (score 0):

OmniThreadLibrary also has a lot of tests
http://otl.17slon.com/index.htm